# Extracting coefficients from sum

Tags: expression-manipulation, coefficients

I'm having the hardest time working if I have a sum of products, with coefficients out the front, like

```
expr = 1 + 2 a[0] b[1] + 2 a[0] b[1] c[3] + c[6] + 5 d[3, 4]
```

How do I get a list of terms with their coefficients, like

```
{ {1, 1}, {2, a[0] b[1]}, {2, a[0] b[1] c[3]}, {1, c[6]}, {5, d[3,4]} }?
```

or even

```
{ {1, 1}, {2, {a[0], b[1]}}, {2, {a[0],b[1],c[3]} }, {1, c[6]}, {5, d[3,4]}}?
```

I've tried:

```
Table[{Coefficient[expr, i], i}, {i, Variables[expr]}]

(* {{2 b[1] + 2 b[1] c[3], a[0]}, {2 a[0] + 2 a[0] c[3], b[1]}, {2 a[0] b[1], c[3]}, {1, c[6]}, {5, d[3, 4]}}  *)
```

But this returns coefficients for the "individual" variables `a[0]`, `b[1]`, `c[1]`, `c[3]`, `d[3,4]`, not the variables as they are grouped in the sum.

I also tried manually picking through the sum, without much success

```
{expr[[2,1]], expr[[2,2;;-1]]} (* want {2, a[0] b[1]} *)

(* {2, a[0],b[1] } *) (* YAY! *)

{expr[[4,1]], expr[[4,2;;-1]]} (* want {1, c[6]} *)

(* {6, c[]} *) (* Oh no... *)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`MonomialList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MonomialList) and [`FactorTermsList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorTermsList). [`MonomialList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MonomialList) gives a list of the monomials (including coefficients) and [`FactorTermsList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorTermsList) gives a 2 element list with the overall numerical factor and the rest of the monomial:

```
expr = 1 + 2 a[0] b[1] + 2 a[0] b[1] c[3] + c[6] + 5 d[3, 4];

FactorTermsList /@ MonomialList[expr]
```

> {{2, a[0] b[1] c[3]}, {2, a[0] b[1]}, {1, c[6]}, {5, d[3, 4]}, {1, 1}}

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** In version 9, there is `` System`ReduceUtilsDump`MonomialCoefficients `` which (when `Transpose`d) gives the desired result.

```
Transpose @ System`ReduceUtilsDump`MonomialCoefficients @ expr
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, a[0] b[1]}, {2, a[0] b[1] c[3]}, {1, c[6]}, {5, d[3, 4]}}

It seems that this function is no longer available in version 11. The following 
implementation is a variation of the code behind `` System`ReduceUtilsDump`MonomialCoefficients ``:

```
ClearAll[coefList]
coefList[a_Times] := Select[a, #] & /@ {NumericQ, Not@*NumericQ}
coefList[a_Plus] := coefList/@(List @@ a)
coefList[a_] := {1, a}

coefList @ expr
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, a[0] b[1]}, {2, a[0] b[1] c[3]}, {1, c[6]}, {5, d[3, 4]}}

**Original answer:**

Using [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html):

```
Replace[List @@ expr, c_.  t__ :> {c, 1 t}, 1]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, a[0] b[1]}, {2, a[0] b[1] c[3]}, {1, c[6]}, {5, d[3, 4]}}

```
Replace[List @@ expr, c_.  t__ :> {c, {t}}, 1]
```

> {{1, {1}}, {2, {a[0], b[1]}}, {2, {a[0], b[1], c[3]}}, {1, {c[6]}}, {5, {d[3, 4]}}}

If you wish you can `Flatten` the first sublist:

```
FlattenAt[%, {{1, 2}}]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, {a[0], b[1]}}, {2, {a[0], b[1], c[3]}}, {1, {c[6]}}, {5, {d[3, 4]}}}